# Can we extract numeric values from string through script in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, kibana-4

I need to extract numeric values from string and store in new field..Can we do this through scripted field?

Ex: 1 hello 3 test

I need to extract 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through logstash if you are using elasticsearch.

Run a logstash process with a config like

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "your_host"
    index => "your_index"
    query => "{ "query": { "match_all": {} } }"
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "your_string_field" => "%{NUMBER:num1} %{GREEDYDATA:middle_stuff} %{NUMBER:num2} %{GREEDYDATA:other_stuff}" }
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["middle_stuff", "other_stuff"]
  }
}
output{
  elasticsearch {
    host => "yourhost"
    index => "your index"
    document_id => %{id}
  }
}
```

This would essentially overwrite each document in your index with two more fields, num1 and num2 that correspond to the numbers that you are looking for.  This is just a quick and dirty approach that would take up more memory, but would allow you to do all of the break up at one time instead of at visualization time.

I am sure there is a way to do this with scripting, look into groovy regex matching where you return a specific group.

Also no guarantee my config representation is correct as I don't have time to test it at the moment.

Have a good day!